# Adding a Footnote to a Figure When Endnotes are in Use

Tags: graphics, positioning, footnotes, includegraphics, endnotes

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage{caption}


\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{color}{\def\Gin@color{#1}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% Remove \fbox separation
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{example-image}=0%
    \begingroup
      \setkeys{Gin}{color=red,#1}% Default color is red
      \colorbox{\Gin@color}{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[13]\footnote{First endnote.}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=3em,height=3em]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large Red Figure}}}
\end{figure}
\vskip 15pt
\lipsum[13]\footnote{Second endnote.}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=3em,height=3em,color=purple]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
       \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large Purple Figure}}}
\end{figure}
\vskip 15pt
\lipsum[13]\footnote{Third endnote.}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=3em,height=3em,color=blue]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
       \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large Blue Figure}}}\footnote{a footnote, not an endnote---I want to display this with an asterisk, and in the usual fashion at the bottom of the first page (NOT IN THE NOTES).}
\end{figure}


\newpage
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: I would like to indicate (endnote) 4 as (footnote) *, positioning the asterisk to the immediate right of the caption, "Blue Figure"; and, displaying the footnote in the usual place under a footnote line near the bottom of page 1---while removing it from the Notes section. How may this be accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: Lose the `\let\footnote=\endnote` so that you can combine endnotes and regular footnotes.

Comment: @JohnKormylo But then the following happens: (i) The first three endnotes appear both as footnotes on the first page, as well as in the Endnotes;  (ii) the (4th) which I want as the only footnote does not appear as a footnote at all; and (iii) All *four* notes appear as endnotes, when I want only the first three to do so.

Comment: You should be able to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` and get the normal versions.  In fact, you should be doing that anyway, putting `\footnotemark` inside the figure and `\footnotetext` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you may have to move `\footnotetext` to another page if the figure floats away.  OTOH, it now ignores the `footnote` counter (`\endnote` uses the counter `endnote`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\def\thefootnote{*}

\usepackage{caption}


\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{color}{\def\Gin@color{#1}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% Remove \fbox separation
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{example-image}=0%
    \begingroup
      \setkeys{Gin}{color=red,#1}% Default color is red
      \colorbox{\Gin@color}{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[13]\footnote{First endnote.}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=3em,height=3em]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large Red Figure}}}
\end{figure}
\vskip 15pt
\lipsum[13]\footnote{Second endnote.}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=3em,height=3em,color=purple]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
       \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large Purple Figure}}}
\end{figure}
\vskip 15pt
\lipsum[13]\footnote{Third endnote.}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=3em,height=3em,color=blue]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
       \caption[]{\textbf{\scshape{\large Blue Figure}}\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{a footnote, not an endnote---I want to display this with an asterisk, and in the usual fashion at the bottom of the first page (NOT IN THE NOTES).}

\newpage
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer.